# Any complex measurable function can be approximated by a sequence of simple functions with increasing norm.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

I'm looking at the proof of $b.$, and I follow everything except the part that the norm of the sequence of simple functions is increasing. Defining each $\phi_n$ as in the proof, how can we show that $|\phi_n|\le |\phi_{n+1}|$? I would greatly appreciate any help.

[image]

Comment: You didn't tell us what part (a) is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will assume that for part a), $\phi$ is defined as $\phi:X\to\mathbb R_+$ because otherwise the definition doesn't make sense. If this is the case, you have to show $\phi_n$ is increasing.

---

To show $\phi_n$ as defined in a) is increasing, we will analyze the possible cases:

If $x$ is such that $f(x)>2^{n+1}$ then $x\in F_n\cap F_{n+1}$. Then $\phi_{n+1}(x)=2^{n+1}>2^{n}=\phi_n(x)$

If $x$ is such that $2^n<f(x)\leq 2^{n+1}$ then $x\in F_n\cap E_{n+1,k}$ for a large enough $k$, such that $f(x)>k2^{-n-1}\geq 2^n$. Then $\phi_{n+1}(x)=k2^{-n-1}\geq 2^n=\phi_n(x)$

If $x$ is such that $f(x)\leq2^n$ then $x\in E_{n,k}\cap E_{n+1,k'}$ for some $k,k'$. Notice
\begin{eqnarray}
(k2^{-n},(k+1)2^{-n}] & = &(2k2^{-n-1},2(k+1)2^{-n-1}]\\
& = & (2k2^{-n-1},(2k+1)2^{-n-1}]\cup((2k+1)2^{-n-1},2(k+1)2^{-n-1}]
\end{eqnarray}
This implies $k'=2k$ or $k'=2k+1$. Then $\phi_{n+1}(x)$ can be either $(2k)2^{-n-1}$ or $(2k+1)2^{-n-1}$ which is greater or equal than $k2^{n}=\phi_n(x)$

---

To show $\phi_n$ as defined in b) has increasing norm, we notice, if $g(x)<0$ then $g^+(x)=0$ and $g^-(x)=-g(x)$ (and conversely if $g(x)>0$, then $g^+(x)=g(x)$ and $g^-(x)=0$). This implies, if $\psi_n^+(x)>0$ then $\psi_n^-(x)=0$ and conversely as well. This implies $\psi_n^+\psi_n^-=0$. This implies $(\psi_n^+-\psi_n^-)^2=(\psi_n^+)^2+(\psi_n^-)^2$, and so it is increasing as sum of increasing sequences. Similarly we show $(\zeta_n^+-\zeta_n^-)^2$ is increasing. Then $\vert \phi_n\vert=\sqrt{(\psi_n^+-\psi_n^-)^2+(\zeta_n^+-\zeta_n^-)^2}$ is increasing